# Xcode not recognizing declared variable?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode6

i have just created a new class within my Controller file like such :

```
import UIKit

class FirstTableViewController: UITableViewController {

class Sport {

    var name: String = "sport name"
    var branches: NSArray = [" branches of this sport"]
}
```

now when i try to create a new object from that class, it works as expected:

```
 var americanFootball = Sport()
```

however when i try to access one of the properties from the class to change, it doesn't recognize my new object:

[image]

whats the issue ?

Comment: You should be using a struct instead a class in this case

Comment: Have a look in apple documentation about classes and structures https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/ClassesAndStructures.html

Comment: You haven't declared a new object. You declared a member of the class FirstTableViewController. Try thinking about when this code will be executed.

Comment: i've read it, seems like a struct would be more simplistic. but they seem very similar, will it alter my results in any way? @IcaroNZ

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should access the property inside a function.

```
import UIKit

class FirstTableViewController:UITableViewController {

class Sport {

    var name: String = "sport name"
    var branches: NSArray = [" branches of this sport"]
}
   var americanFootball = Sport()//This is a property of FirstTableViewController 

   override func viewDidLoad() {
        americanFootball.name = "Another"
   }

}
```

Comment: can you provide an example with regards to the data i showed in the question?

Comment: See updates. Your error is you want  `declare area` to execute code.

Comment: so it was giving the error because of where i declared it?

Comment: Because you want to execute code on declare area